# Basic MySQL PATH question

Tags: mysql

In the Terminal prompt, I have to type in $ PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH to run MySQL commands.

Where do I need to save this path in the MySQL files, such that I don't need to type in this path every time I enter into the terminal path. What file, and where should I type this in?

Thank you.

Where can I find the .bashrc file? when I do a cd ~, then ls -a, it does not show up (although I do see a .bash_history.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to save `$PATH` in mysql, you need to save it in your `.profile` or `.bashrc` (substitute for your own shell if not Bash) files, found in your home directory.

You have files like these without the dot in frontne in `/etc`, but they're the system wide ones (they are the default to all users). You should have a file `.bashrc` or `.profile` (or you could create them if they don't exist) in your `/home/David542` directory (with your own username, of course).

Caveat: depending on your system, you could be using a shell different from bash, so you'd have to create a different dot file (`.kshrc`, `.cshrc`, `.shrc`, etc).

Comment: I found it -- in my /etc directory -- and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`.bashrc` in your home directory